# including a php file using <a> tags

Tags: php

I have been trying to include a php file using  tags.
I am running my script in a local server.

Whenever I click on the link 
my browser keeps the page redirects to
"

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 403 localhost Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11

"
my code looks like:

```
<a href= "<?php include 'login.php';?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: Ouch. You need to read some beginner tutorials about includes in PHP to get the basics right.

Comment: Why would you execute the contents of the file in the `href` of an anchor tag. If you want to link to the file, then simply link to it `<a href="login.php">Login</a>`. The [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement evaluates the file's contents. It does not create a link to the file. Whatever output comes from `login.php` (if any) will be displayed in the `href` property...

Comment: If you want to include a file based on a condition, then use `if(condition equals something){ include the file }else echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Login</a>";`, otherwise just do a direct link instead of what you're doing now.

Comment: View the HTML output in the browser and check what that link links to. That might make it a bit clear to you. If not, please watch this *[very informative video about client vs server](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-php-application/getting-started-with-php/serverside-versus-clientside-2)*.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, my intent is not to redirect to the login.php. I actually intend to include the php script in the current page. If you have something for that, then you would be helping. Otherwise I had considered the other options you have offered

Comment: Why don't you want to redirect to the login page? Or, why do you make it a link if you don't want to redirect to it? A link typically sends you to another page. Also, that is a client side action (see also my comment above).

Comment: *"I actually intend to include the php script in the current page."* - Just do `<?php include 'file.php';`, that's it; it doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: @Fred, I will go by you previous answer...because I actually want include the script on a certain condition. Thank you.

Comment: *"I actually intend to include the php script in the current page."* - [Seems like I had anticipated for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999466/including-a-php-file-using-a-tags#comment38869223_24999466). I must be psychic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. When you click that link you're telling the browser that it should be navigating to the url (insert result of login.php here) which isn't going to work. You can link like this:
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>
or include it in your php script at the appropriate time like:
include "login.php"
Right-click the link you've generated and select properties. You'll see there exactly what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead

```
<a href="login.php">Login</a>
```